# pdflatex index shows up in pdf-contents but not in toc

Tags: pdftex, indexing

I ran the LaTeX file below with 
`pdflatex`, `makeindex` and again `pdflatex`. 
The index shows up in the ind-file and the index shows up in the contents in my pdf-viewer but I need two further `pdflatex` runs 
to make the index show up in the toc. 
Is this a problem with `tocbibind`?

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[notbib]{tocbibind} % problem with latex2rtf 

\usepackage{makeidx} % problem with latex2rtf 
\makeindex % to create file .idx
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % to create file .toc
%\newpage

\section{Introduction}

The present document describes a very simple programming language, 
S (for Simple, Stream-Oriented or Strictly-Typed), the name of which is inspired by C. 


\index{array}
An {\em array} consists of a definite number of entries 
all of the same type $T$, 
accessible via an index which is a non-negative index number of type $\I$. 

\printindex

\bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you compile the document the first time, the table of contents will be empty. Then you run `makeindex` and in the next compilation the index will be included; in the next compilation also the entry for the TOC will be available. It's perfectly normal. But from the third run on you won't need three runs each time. If you want to be sure the page numbers are synchronized in the TOC, run LaTeX twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typesetting of the table of contents happens in an asynchronous way. At each run of LaTeX, the data collected in the preceding run is used for the table of contents.

So if you don't have a `.toc` file yet, here's what happens:

1. First run of LaTeX: the `.toc` is opened and written, but it will contain only the data related to the sections already “seen”; the index has not yet been produced. The table of contents will be empty.
2. Run of MakeIndex: the index is compiled.
3. Second run of LaTeX: the index is included in the document, the table of contents will contain the entries for the sections collected in the first run (not the index, because it was not there). In the `.toc` file, an entry for the index is written out.
4. Third run of LaTeX: the index will appear in the table of contents.

What can happen in the following runs of LaTeX is that the table of contents grows and so possibly changes page references. Just run LaTeX after each run of MakeIndex.